# Why does simplehtmldom kicks me out of loop with no error?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am having a problem with simplehtmldom I've tracked it down to this code block.  I have about 70 different urls that I am trying to scrape, but my loop only goes through two.  On the second iteration file_get_html($url) only returns part of the page into $html.  The embedded foreach loop will run and print out the partial page, then it will kick me out of both loops without hitting the last print.  The strangest part about this is it does not give a warning or an error.

```
foreach($urls as $url)
        {    
            $html = file_get_html( $url );
            $appList = $html->find("loc");
            foreach($appList as $each)
            {
                print "$each \n";
            }
            print "hello\n";

        }
```

Please do not give answers that just ignore the second $url and continue to the next iteration.  I need all of the information on each page

Comment: Your code is fine, AFAICT. Maybe it's a URL-specific issue? Which URL are you trying to parse, if I can ask?

Comment: I didn't want to give out the url but it is http://www.brothersoft.com/sitemap.php?pageno=2 that is giving me the issue the outer loop goes through pageno1-77

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: What is reporting and how do I turn it on? I'm assuming this will give me my invisible error

Comment: If you start at url3 does it do the same thing and die part way through url4? Might give interesting info in determining if it is the program or the urls that are to blame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using plain regular expressions and curl.  This was an xml page so

```
preg_match_all("@<loc.*?\/loc>@",$curlHTML,$locTags)
```

worked just fine, but I never figured out what was going on with simple_html_dom